# Questions related to $(a^2 - b^2)(a^4-b^4) \le (a^3 - b^3)^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

This is a follow up to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/298670/inequality-problem-a2-b2a4-b4-le-a3-b32) question, from Beckenbach and Bellman's Introduction to Inequalities.

Briefly, the question asks, in part to

> Show that $(a^2 - b^2)(a^4-b^4) \le (a^3 - b^3)^2$

As this is not an attempt to find out the answer, I will give the book's answer

> Equivalent to $a^2b^2(a-b)^2 \ge 0$

**Question 1: Style**
\begin{align}
(a^2 - b^2)(a^4-b^4) &\le (a^3 - b^3)^2\\
{a}^{6} - {a}^{4}{b}^{2} - {a}^{2}{b}^{4} + b^6 &\le {a}^{6} -2a^3b^3 + b^6 
\end{align}

Clearly, the second inequality is an expansion of the first. It seems using either of the operators $\implies$ or $\iff$as in

\begin{align}
(a^2 - b^2)(a^4-b^4) &\le (a^3 - b^3)^2\\
\implies {a}^{6} - {a}^{4}{b}^{2} - {a}^{2}{b}^{4} + b^6 &\le {a}^{6} -2a^3b^3 + b^6 
\end{align}

or

\begin{align}
(a^2 - b^2)(a^4-b^4) &\le (a^3 - b^3)^2\\
\iff {a}^{6} - {a}^{4}{b}^{2} - {a}^{2}{b}^{4} + b^6 &\le {a}^{6} -2a^3b^3 + b^6 
\end{align}

does not quite convey how the first and second inequalities are related. I would appreciate some input here.

**Question 2: Algebraic manipulations**

Once the inequality ${a}^{6} - {a}^{4}{b}^{6} - {a}^{2}{b}^{4} + b^6 \le {a}^{6} -2a^3b^3 + b^6$ is achieved, it seems there are at least 2 legitimate ways ( probably a lot more) of proceeding.

Path (i)

\begin{align}
(a^2 - b^2)(a^4-b^4) &\le (a^3 - b^3)^2\\
{a}^{6} - {a}^{4}{b}^{2} - {a}^{2}{b}^{4} + b^6 &\le {a}^{6} -2a^3b^3 + b^6 \\
  - {a}^{4}{b}^{2} - {a}^{2}{b}^{4}  &\le  -2a^3b^3\\
 \frac {- {a}^{4}{b}^{2} - {a}^{2}{b}^{4}}{a^2b^2}  &\le  \frac{-2a^3b^3} {a^2b^2}\\
- {a}^{2} - {b}^{2}  &\le  -2ab\\
-(a-b)^2 &\le 0 \implies (a-b)^2 \ge 0
\end{align}

Path(ii)

\begin{align}
(a^2 - b^2)(a^4-b^4) &\le (a^3 - b^3)^2\\
{a}^{6} - {a}^{4}{b}^{2} - {a}^{2}{b}^{4} + b^6 &\le {a}^{6} -2a^3b^3 + b^6 \\
  - {a}^{4}{b}^{2} - {a}^{2}{b}^{4}  &\le  -2a^3b^3\\
 - {a}^{4}{b}^{2}  + 2a^3b^3 - {a}^{2}{b}^{4}  &\le 0 \\
 - ({a}^{2}{b}^{2})({a}^{2}  - 2ab + b^{2}) &\le 0 \\
- ({a}^{2}{b}^{2})(a - b)^2 &\le 0  \implies ({a}^{2}{b}^{2})(a - b)^2 \ge 0
\end{align}

It seems both pathways are legitimate, but I am uncomfortable with the different results, which seemingly do not invalidate the proof. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Path (i) implicitly assumes that $a, b \ne 0$ at the point where $a^2b^2$ is divided out.

Comment: @dxiv. Thank you so much, and that makes perfect sense. No where in the question did it make that assumption. It certainly removes the ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to approach it for the sake of curiosity.

Suppose that $a\neq b$, otherwise the inequality is trivial.

Then one gets that:
\begin{align*}
(a^{2} - b^{2})(a^{4} - b^{4}) \leq (a^{3} - b^{3})^{2} & \Longleftrightarrow (a - b)(a + b)(a^{2} - b^{2})(a^{2} + b^{2}) \leq (a - b)^{2}(a^{2} + ab + b^{2})^{2}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (a - b)^{2}(a + b)^{2}(a^{2} + b^{2}) \leq (a - b)^{2}(a^{2} + ab + b^{2})^{2}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (a + b)^{2}(a^{2} + b^{2}) \leq (a^{2} + ab + b^{2})^{2}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (a + b)^{2}[(a - b)^{2} + 2ab] \leq (a^{2} + ab + b^{2})^{2}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (a^{2} - b^{2})^{2} + 2ab(a + b)^{2} \leq (a^{2} + ab + b^{2})^{2}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow 2ab(a + b)^{2} \leq (a^{2} + ab + b^{2})^{2} - (a^{2} - b^{2})^{2}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow 2ab(a + b)^{2} \leq (2a^{2} + ab)(2b^{2} + ab)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow 2ab(a^{2} + 2ab + b^{2}) \leq 4a^{2}b^{2} + 2a^{3}b + 2ab^{3} + a^{2}b^{2}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow 2a^{3}b + 4a^{2}b^{2} + 2ab^{3} \leq 4a^{2}b^{2} + 2a^{3}b + 2ab^{3} + a^{2}b^{2}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow a^{2}b^{2} \geq 0
\end{align*}
which is always true.

Hopefully this contributes!

Comment: I am especially interested in your use of $\iff$ here. Surely the first half of the inequality equals the second half, so for example, why not use $\implies$. This was part of my original question, so explaining that here would be very instructive.

Comment: @user1115542 The only step which could generate invalid conclusions concerns the division by $(a - b)^{2}$. But there is no problem at doing so, because we have assumed that $a\neq b$ (when $a = b$, the inequality holds trivially). Hence all the equivalences are correct.

Comment: OK…so if I am understanding you correctly, the use of $\iff$ here is actually crucial as it, by its implication, says $a \neq b$. And this was not stated in the question. Your comment is in line with the comment made above by @dxiv and helps explain a lot. Thanks.

Comment: @user1115542 The question did not suggest to consider each case separately, but there is no harm in doing so.

Comment: Understood. But, your answer, if I understand you correctly, helps me understand that the use of $\iff$ eliminates any ambiguity. Perhaps inadvertently, you have answered my question, for which I am grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $a^2 + b^2 - 2ab = (a-b)^2 \ge 0$, hence $- 2ab \ge -a^2 - b^2$. Multiply the last inequality by $a^2b^2 \ge 0$ we get $- 2a^3 b^3 \ge -a^4 b^2 - a^2 b^4$. Thus,
$$(a^3 - b^3)^2 = a^6 + b^6 - 2 a^3 b^3 \ge a^6  +b^6 - a^4 b^2 -a^2 b^4 = (a^2 - b^2)(a^4-b^4).$$